# Pagefiling an unformatted SSD

Tags: windows-8, ssd, pagefile

Now, before you people start rambling on about how SSD are not anything like the RAM, I shouldn't be using it for pagefile because it'll get written on too much, etc etc. I already know about that and am willing to take the risk.

I do know how to enable pagefiling on hard disks, etc. However my SSD that shipping stock as a hybrid in my laptop is *unformatted* resulting in it not showing up in a list of hard drives to use for pagefile. It is, however (the SSD that is) listed as a separate drive in task manager, device manager and disk management. I do not wish to format the SSD as the OS has already been installed on the HDD (bloody OEM manufacturers) and will be of minimal use to me whilst formatted. Hence why I am trying just to use a small amount (4-6GB of the 24GB of the SSD), whilst the SSD is unformatted, to be used as pagefile. Is this possible?

Also note, I am on windows 8.

Comment: Have you partitioned the SSD? Your SSD can't actually be either formatted or unformatted, as you don't format drives, you format partitions.

Comment: If it shipped as a hybrid, it would have been a Logical Volume Group, which you could have broken trying to format it yourself. A tiny SSD would have been more use as a hybrid than it would be as pagefile.

Comment: I have not yet partitioned the SSD. It is a completely RAW SSD - no format, no partitions. In answer to +Tetsujin : I have not touched the SSD since I have been in ownership of the laptop, however the retail store I purchased it from may have modified it, that I am not sure of. Also, I have run benchmarks over several hours on the SSD, and during usage of the computer, i.e. general applications, games (bf4/3, etc) and web usage, the SSD is not being used at all. 0% usage over the entirety of the time that I have run benchmarks and observed the drive (which is a long time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: Windows can not swap to a raw disk/partition, you have to format it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought it would be as much, so I am now looking to use IntelRST to use the SSD for cache instead (as I don't particularly want to mess around with the formatting and partitioning too much).